# Angular 9 error = type assignable to very few other types

Tags: angular

I have created the following simple data source service which returns a list of quotes from a back end API to display in a table:

```
export class QuoteDataSource implements DataSource<Quote> {

    private quotesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Quote[]>([]);
    private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor(private quoteService: QuoteService) {}

    connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Quote[]> {
        return this.quotesSubject.asObservable();
    }

    disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
        this.quotesSubject.complete();
        this.quotesSubject.complete();
    }

    loadQuotes() {
        this.quoteService.getQuotes().pipe(
            finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
        )
        .subscribe(quotes => this.quotesSubject.next(quotes));
    }
}
```

However, the compiler returns the following error during build:

```
 The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
        Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Quote[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

    31         .subscribe(quotes => this.quotesSubject.next(quotes));``
```

Therefore it looks the problem is the following line:

```
.subscribe(quotes => this.quotesSubject.next(quotes));
```

I have tried the following alternatives with no luck:

```
.subscribe(quotes => this.quotesSubject.next(Quote[]));
```

and also:

```
.subscribe(quotes => this.quotesSubject.next(Quote));
```

below is the function for this.quoteService.getQuotes() which returns a JOSN array of quotes:

```
    getQuotes() {
        const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/quotes/list`;

        return this.http.get(url, {}).pipe(
            map( res => res)
        );
    }
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong but hopefully somebody can.

Musaffar

Comment: What does `quoteService.getQuotes()` return?

Comment: Hi @Liam, I've added the function to my question, it returns an array of quotes

Comment: Why are you doing this? `map( res => res)` that's literally pointless? do `this.http.get<Quote[]>(...)` to return an array of quotes.  Also add a type to your function `getQuotes(): Quote[]`

Comment: I'm pretty much ignoring your `QuoteDataSource` which seems incredibly over engineered/confusing

Comment: This is my first angular project so bare with me, much of the code has come from the Angular University tutorials.   Adding <Quote[]> to the http.get call fixes the error.  However changing the method signature to getQuotes(): Quote[] produces more errors.  If it's not too much trouble, how would you rewrite the getQuotes function?   My main problem is already solved (within minutes) so I'm very grateful for that

Comment: Try this `getQuotes(): Observable<Quote[]> { const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/quotes/list`;  return this.http.get(url, {}); }`

Comment: Well it seems to me that `QuoteDataSource` is just a pointless middle man. If you want some quotes just call `this.quoteService.getQuotes().subscribe()`, delete `QuoteDataSource` and forget it ever existed

Comment: I completely agree. `QuoteDataSource` could be a culprit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will remove the datasource and thanks for identifying the problem and helping me clean up the getQuotes function too.

Comment: has it resolved your problem completely ?

Comment: @micronyks yes, the original issue is completely resolved now

Comment: Cool.. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `pipe` operator as you don't want to process the response.

```
getQuotes(): Observable<Quote[]> {

        const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/quotes/list`;

        return this.http.get(url, {});
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the feedback rewriting the getQuotes function to the following resolved the issue:

```
    getQuotes(): Observable<Quote[]> {
        const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/quotes/list`;
        return this.http.get<Quote[]>(url, {});
    }
```

Musaffar